# How to get proper kotlin types from RoundEnvironment for custom Annotation processor?

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, kotlinpoet

Lets say my annotation processor's process function looks like below

```
override fun process(
        annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>,
        roundEnv: RoundEnvironment
    ): Boolean {
        try {
            roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation::class.java)
                .mapNotNull {
                    if (it.kind != ElementKind.INTERFACE) {
                        printError(
                            "Only interfaces can be annotated with " +
                                    MapperConfig::class.java.simpleName
                        )
                        null
                    } else {
                        it as TypeElement
                    }
                }.forEach {
                    processMapperConfigInterface(it, roundEnv)
                }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            messager.printError(ex.message!!)
        }
        return true
    }
```

`roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith` returns me tthe java Elements without any kotlin type information, how do I use annotation processing to get proper kotlin type information instead?

Comment: Quick answer to guys comings here, throw away kotlin poett use Google's KSP instead, 
github.com/google/ksp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only solution I could come up with, is to parse the element's metadata using the [kotlinpoet-metadata API](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/kotlinpoet_metadata/).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** `kotlinpoet-metadata` is still early in production and is itself based on the experimental `kotlinx-metadata` library, so things might break in the future. However, it is currently used in the stable version of the [Moshi Kotlin code generator](https://github.com/square/moshi#codegen).

First, make sure that you've added the following to your dependencies in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup:kotlinpoet-metadata:1.7.1'`
}
```

1.7.1 is the latest KotlinPoet version as of today.

You can get the Kotlin type information via a `KmClass`, constructed from your element's metadata. Here's an example on using [KmClass](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/kotlinpoet_metadata/#example) and here's what you would need to change in your code:

```
override fun process(
    annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>,
    roundEnv: RoundEnvironment
): Boolean {
    try {
        roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation::class.java)
            .mapNotNull {
                if (it.kind != ElementKind.INTERFACE) {
                    printError(
                        "Only interfaces can be annotated with " +
                                MapperConfig::class.java.simpleName
                    )
                    null
                } else {
                    it as TypeElement
                }
            }.forEach {
                val typeMetadata = it.getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java) ?: return@forEach
                var kmClass = typeMetadata.toImmutableKmClass()
                // HERE: kmClass should contain all the Kotlin type information.
            }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        messager.printError(ex.message!!)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: cool, thats what i was missing thank you very much!

Comment: @Bhargav if you're not too far into your work with Kapt, you might also consider taking a look at Ksp: https://github.com/google/ksp 
That's what I finally ended up using, and I have to say it's a far more pleasant experience :)